# How do I know whether a sklearn scaler is already fitted or not?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For example, `ss` is an `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` object. If `ss` is fitted already, I want to use it to transform my data. If `ss` is not fitted yet, I want to use my data to fit it and transform my data. Is there a way to know whether `ss` is already fitted or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sklearn implements the [check_is_fitted](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html) function to check if any generic estimator is fitted, which works with StandardScaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted

ss = StandardScaler()
check_is_fitted(ss) # Raises error

ss.fit([[1,2,3]])
check_is_fitted(ss) # No error
```

Answer (score 2):

According to you example, in order to determine if your object is a `Fitted scaler`, one checks if the attribute `n_features_in_` exists in the object of interest.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler_fit = StandardScaler().fit(data)

def is_fit_called(obj):
    return hasattr(obj, "n_features_in_")

print(is_fit_called(scaler)) #False
print(is_fit_called(scaler_fit)) #True
```